# Entity relation with two many to one relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to implement user invitations and i have a little problem with mapping entities. I have User entity which have set of invitations and a invitation have User field and inviting User field. In this way I have two User fields that are the same.

User side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
public Set<Invitation> invitations;
```

Invitation:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idInvitingUser", insertable=false, updatable=false)
public User invitingUser;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idUser")
public User user;
```

How can I map this proper ?

Comment: Hey ! Please elaborate, in your User table we have invitation(OneToMany) which states we have for one user many invitation entry in user table. And in Invitation table we have ManyToOne with User (that too type of User). I want to know what comes as data in inviataion table for two different users. Could you please give a bit of more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you will need two sets of invitations on the user side: invitations sent and invitations received.

UPDATE:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
public Set<Invitation> invitations;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="invitingUser")
public Set<Invitation> invitationsSent;
```

Comment: but even with that how can I say that the list is pointing to the right field ?